# Google Cloud Services: Editing VM instance "iq-wealth-wordpress-vm" failed. Error: Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API'

Tags: service, cloud, virtual-machine

I'm trying to restore a snapshot to my VM instance, but it's giving me this error when saving the snap shot as an additional disk. It won't save the disk. This is like a 911 situation. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you been whitelisted for Alpha access? Any alpha features need whitelisting from Google.